# Draw a triangulation of a sphere

Tags: graphics3d

I want to draw a triangulation of a sphere starting from the following data.
I have a collection of triangles represented by three points $(p1,p2,p3)$ on a sphere of radius 1.
I would like to draw in a different color (or maybe even with a texture) each curvy triangle.
Any ideas?

EDIT

Thanks for the first answers. Both method works fine, but there is something else that now bothers me.

For each triangle I have a picture that I would like to use as a Texture, each picture has a central "body" surrounded by white empty space that can be increased at pleasure. I would like the Texture to be added so that the central body ends up on the barycenter of the triangle and I would like it not to be too deformed.
In other words, what I would like to happen is to cut a triangle out of the original picture and use it as a texture so that the vertices and barycenter (the central body) are mapped to vertices and barycenter of the spherical triangles.
Here is an example of a picture

[image]

Also, I would like to be able to "see through" the regions, so that one can see the central body drawn on the far side of the sphere without rotating it. If I use PlotStyle->{Texture[Image],Opacity[.5]} from your first Method, the texture completely disappears.

Comment: The surface of a sphere is two-dimensional. Only two coordinates are needed. You already specified the radius. Or, have you computed already the three dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method-1

- `ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}}, {p1, p2, p3}]` generate the infinite pyramid.
  $$\{ t_1p1+t_2p_2+t_3p_3, t_1,t_2,t_3\geq 0 \}$$
- The spherical triangle is the intersection of the`ConicHullRegion` region and `Sphere[]`.

```
SeedRandom[1];
sphere = Sphere[];
{p1, p2, p3} = RandomPoint[sphere, 3];
viewpoint = Mean[{p1, p2, p3}];
reg = DiscretizeRegion[
   RegionIntersection[{sphere, 
     ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}}, {p1, p2, p3}]}], {{-1.2, 
     1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-5, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 3];
sphericaltriangle = 
 RegionPlot3D[reg, 
  PlotStyle -> Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}]], 
  Mesh -> None]
Graphics3D[{sphere, sphericaltriangle[[1]]}, ViewPoint -> viewpoint, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

### Method-2

- For three points`{p1,p2,p3}`, we parametric the space triangle by

```
{1 - t, t} . {p1, {1 - s, s} . {p2, p3}}
```

where `0<=t<=1` and `0<=s<=1`. After that we `Normalize` all of  the points of triangle to projecte it to the unit-sphere.

```
SeedRandom[1];
sphere = Sphere[];
{p1, p2, p3} = RandomPoint[sphere, 3];
ParametricPlot3D[{1 - t, t} . {p1, {1 - s, s} . {p2, p3}} // 
  Normalize, {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture@ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "GoldenOak"}], 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: The second method is very elegant. And nice use of the texture data!